# n-th child with automatic color select?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a navigation with several `<li>` items.

Every `<li>` has it's own class  (nav-1, nav-2, etc.)

Now I'd like to give each class a **different background color**.

Is there a way to do this in one single css-tag?

Because over the time my menu will grow and I don't want to put my hand on every change.
I.e. something like

```
color: #eee +X;
```

Comment: A repeated, known quantity of colors (like zebra striping)? or an incremental change almost like a gradient?

Comment: more like a gradient (non repeating)

Comment: You can't just put the css in for a few dozen items up front? Otherwise, how will the menu grow? Is there some automated process that adds items?

Comment: yes, the menu items are added in a backend-system. later php calls every category

Answer (score 0):

There are `counters` in CSS, however it is not possible to retreive counters' value using `attr()` and then insert that value to `calc()`.

If it is sufficient for you, you could cycle, for example, five colors. The code would look like this.

```
li:nth-of-type(5n+1) { color:#000; }
li:nth-of-type(5n+2) { color:#333; }
li:nth-of-type(5n+3) { color:#666; }
li:nth-of-type(5n+4) { color:#999; }
li:nth-of-type(5n)   { color:#CCC; }
```

Or you could use javascript (jQuery possibly) to do the job.